# display of blocks when changing tabs

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the panel with tabs and a panel with content `container`. 
When switching tabs, only div should be changed, and `header` should be displayed in all tabs.
I use the event `selectedTabChange()` that is listened to to check which tab is active and show the necessary div tag. What should I write to `selectedTabChange()`

.html:

```
            <mat-tab label="first"></mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="second"></mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="third"></mat-tab>
          </mat-tab-group>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="header">Header</div>
            <div *ngIf="isBlock2! && !isBlock3" class="block1">Text</div>
            <div *ngIf="isBlock1! && !isBlock3" class="block2">Text</div>
            <div *ngIf="isBlock1! && !isBlock2" class="block3">Text</div>
          </div>
```

.ts:

```
   public isBlock2 = false;
   public isBlock3 = false;

  changeTabs(event) : void {
      isBlock1 != isBlock1; 
  }
```

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can use

> ng-template and ng-container

Demo:

[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j8olyc)

```
selectedTabChangeEvent(event){
    this.isBlock1 = false;
    this.isBlock2 = false;
    this.isBlock3 = false;    
    if(event.index === 0){
        this.isBlock1 = true;
    }else if(event.index === 1){
        this.isBlock2 = true;    
    }else {
       this.isBlock3=true;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Try something like this